# Canceling domain name effects in nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, whm

I have 5 domain in cpanel, one of the domain name is (just say) **abc.com** , nameserver name is **ns1.abc.com** and **ns2.abc.com** for all 5 domains, Here I have to delete account and don't want to renew abc.com. Will it affect other domain working? Becoze nameserver name and domain name are same ABC... does nameserver name require valid hosted domain?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, to function correctly your NS records need to point to existing and valid host names.

There are some performance and administrative benefits when you operate several domain including the `example.com` , `example.org`,  `example.net` domains (and possibly many, many more when you're a for example a hosting provider or cybersquatter)  to configure all of them to use `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com` as the authoritative  name servers.

Such a configuration will significantly reduce the administrative effort when for example when you need to change your network layout. When that is necessary you only need to update two DNS records and all your domains will follow and use the new IP-addresses for `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`.

The disadvantage is that when you want to get rid of the `example.com` domain, (for whatever reasons, re-branding, a merger etc. etc.) you really can't until all the domains are updated with new NS records...

Generally speaking though the registration fees of a domain are not too exorbitant and therefore simply keeping a legacy domain operational is no significant burden and only visible when somebody takes an in-depth look at your DNS, hardly something that the typical web site visitor, customer or supplier is likely to do.

---

The alternative is that you configure each domain with in-zone NS records, sometimes also called private name server records.

To change to such a configuration both the `example.org` zone data and registration entry at your registrar needs to be changed from

```
@             IN  NS    ns1.example.com.
@             IN  NS    ns2.example.com.
```

to something like

```
@             IN  NS    ns1.example.org.
@             IN  NS    ns2.example.org.
ns1.example.org. IN A   10.9.8.7
ns2.example.org. IN A   10.11.12.13
```

and similarly for example.net to

```
@             IN  NS    ns1.example.net.
@             IN  NS    ns2.example.net.
ns1.example.net. IN A   10.9.8.7
ns2.example.net. IN A   10.11.12.13
```